# VBA: How to find the next cell in the same row (excluding hidden cells)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've used a Vlookup to return values in column I, however only half of the cells in this column returned a value (the other half are blank).  I'd like my Macro to enter a space " " in all of the empty Vlookup cells rather than keeping the Vlookup equation in the cell.  I want to filer all the values in the column and then change the blank cells to =" "

My ultimate goal is to post a Note on each line based on whether cell I has a value or a blank.  If cell I for any given line is blank, the cell in column K for that line will auto-fill "Processed Not Yet Paid", if there is a value in cell I, cell K will auto-fill "Paid"

My problem is that I don't know how to write an equation that avoids the hidden cells (hidden from the filter) and changes only the values of the cells displayed after the filter.  My column headers are in row 4 and my code is presented below:

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A4:K" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$K" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="="
Range("I4").Offset(1, 0) = " "
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Range("I4").Offset(1, 0):I" & 
Lastrow)
```

Comment: Why don't you just wrap your original `VLOOKUP` formulas in an `IFERROR` to get your space that you want? Something like `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: It is not quite clear either what you do  or why you do it, or what is your ultimate goal for that matter. Could you please re-write you question to be more clear?

Comment: The Iferror function does not work for my ultimate goal of auto-filling cells based on whether they are blank or have a value.  I've updated my question to include my ultimate goal.  Please let me know if there is a better way to go about this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can solve your problem. Firstly, you could just put a formula in column K to check if cells in column I are blank:

`=IF(I4<>"","Paid","Processed Not Yet Paid")`

[image: Processed Not Yet Paid]

Or if you're *really* looking for a macro solution, just go down cell by cell and check the values:

```
Sub WhoDidntPay()
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To lastrow
    If ActiveSheet.Range("I" & i).Value <> "" And _
       ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).Value = <> 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Value = "Processed Not Yet Paid"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Value = "Paid"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Again, I suggest adding an `IFERROR` to your `VLOOKUP`s so that you can return a consistent value if you're getting errors, or if they're really returning blanks, can just use `""` like in the example above.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your code worked for my problem perfectly

Comment: Is there a way that I could add another condition to the first part of the If statement that says in the value in I is " " and the value in G is 0, then place "Paid" into column K?

Comment: I appreciate your patience as I'm a beginner with VBA, this returned an error.  I wrote the wrong objective in my last comment.  I'd like "Paid" to be returned in column K if both a value is present in Column I and the value in column G is 0 (this pertains to the Else segment).  Again I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @oryan5000 No worries. I've edited the code once more. As long as column I isn't blank (`""`), and column G has a 0 in it, column K will show "Paid"

Comment: For some reason blanks are not being created in Column I.  The table that the information is being pulled from has a the number that matches up with my reference, it's just that the column requesting to be returned has nothing in it for some.  Is there a way you'd alter the IfError statement given this information?

Comment: @oryan5000 A couple times you've said they have "nothing" in it, and you've shown that with `" "` which is different from `""`, what is being returned into the cells??

Comment: No space "" is being returned.  I need to return a space " "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156375/discussion-between-dwirony-and-oryan5000).